# How to save only RealmObject but not referenced object

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

In my app I has the following RealmObjects:

**Product** - This act as master data and should never be modified.
**Cart** - Shopping Cart to allow people to pick stuff to buy. The content will be Selection type.
**Selection** - Represent Product that user selected alongside extra preferences such as color, size, etc.

**Use Case**
User select Product and add to Cart. Product get wrapped inside Selection and stored inside Cart. Say the pick Product A, B, and C.

Now to save that into Realm. Document tells me to use `RealmList` to add relationship. That makes Cart -> List; Selection -> Product.

Then if I use `copyToRealm`, I'll get **PrimaryKey exception on Product**.
Since I want to save **only Cart and Selection**, how do I make Selection link to Product(For reading back up) but not saving it.

If I use `copyToRealmOrUpdate`, do I risk accidentally updating the Product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the RealmObject explicitly inside the Realm from the start, and set the object link to a managed object inside your managed object.

```
realm.executeTransaction((realm) -> {
    // ASSUMING PRIMARY KEY
    Selection selection = realm.where(Selection.class).equalTo(SelectionFields.ID, selectionId).findFirst();
    if(selection == null) {
       selection = realm.createObject(Selection.class, selectionId);
    }
    // here, selection is always managed

    //...
    Product product = realm.where(Product.class)./*...*/.findFirst();
    selection.setProduct(product);

    // no insertOrUpdate()/copyToRealmOrUpdate() call for `selection`
});
```

---

But you can also set the product link only after you turned the proxy to managed.

```
realm.executeTransaction((realm) -> {
    Selection selection = new Selection();

    // assuming selection.getProduct() == null

    selection = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(selection);
    // selection is now managed

    Product product = realm.where(Product.class)./*...*/.findFirst();
    selection.setProduct(product);

    // no insertOrUpdate()/copyToRealmOrUpdate() call for `selection`
});
```

Comment: I ended up going with the latter option. The main gripe for me is now I have to keep both product and productId field in Selection object.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to store **Product** then you can store only it IDs inside your objects. If you will use `copyToRealmOrUpdate` - you may accidentally update your object, because this method performs deep copy.